# Disable php-redis in Nitro

Tags: nitro, redis

Due to a limitation at a Client's server environment (they do not have php-redis enabled) I need to imitate that setup with Nitro. I want to disable PHP's redis extension (C) and use https://github.com/predis/predis instead.

I found the `nitro extensions` command, but this a.) seems to **enable** extension only and b.) does not list redis.

Any suggestions where to start?

Thanks,
Matthias

Comment: Your client has a redis server available to use but not the client library? That seems odd? In most distros it's literally a command or 2 a way to get the client library versus going to down a rabbit hole...   if you're planning on using it with Craft you'd also probably need to figure out how to get it work with the  yii2-redis extension.  If your client is pushing back, I'd ask them if spending half a day messing around with this is worth their time or just spend 10 minutes installing the client library?

Comment: To get prerdis inside a Craft project, you can use composer: ``composer require predis/predis``

Comment: @RitterKnight: yes, it is weird, but it seems we are getting it (php-redis) now. so you can ignore the question. The distribution btw. is RHEL (don't know which version) without any foreign repos. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Going to go ahead and vote to close this as it seems to be a non-issue, now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's not an issue anymore.